# Android - Retrieving image blob form SQLite DB without using bitmaps or decodeStream

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, out-of-memory

Android - I am getting image as JPEG from an URL and storing it in binary form in SQLite DB.
Then while retrieving the same blob from DB, I am getting it as bytearray nad converting it as bitmap, using **decodeStream**; this causes **OutOfMemory** and so I have used **inSampleSize** to scale the image.

But my requirement is not to scale the image, so is there any other way to **get image from DB without using bitmaps and decodeStream**.

Also is there any way in android to retrieve image from DB in its native format(JPEG)?

Comment: There is no way. You must convert in into `Bitmap` and then set it to your `ImageView`. and Scale image is not your requirement it's solution for `OutOfMemory Exception`.

Comment: Thanks for you information @MD, Is there any official documentation for this. Please provide the link.

Comment: see [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: how big is your bytearray?

Comment: *But my requirement is not to scale the image* ... you are wrong ... **you really don't need not scaled image as Bitmap** (look out for double negation :))

Answer (score 0):

I now understand that, this process cannot be done without Bitmaps.
But still I resolved this issue without scaling the image.
I added the following in my Manifest,

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

under application tag.

I understand that this may cause some serious performance issue to the app. Just a temporary solution.
I have also started to clean my code and try to use my heap more efficiently.

Thanks all!! :)